# Select files and merge with same filename but different extension

Tags: 18.04, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of MP4s and Wav files in a folder with the same filenames, different file extension.

I want to replace the audio in the video files with the wav.

i.e. something like this:

```
for i in *.MP4; 
 do ffmpeg -i "$i" -i "${i%.*}.wav" -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 
 "${i%.*}_merged.mp4"; done
```

Is this the right way to merge all the files?

Comment: Looks good except for the newline after `1:a:0`: your shell may interpret `"${i%.*}_merged.mp4"; done` as a separate command. Consider adding `-movflags +faststart` if the videos are intended for progressive playback (such as on a web site hosted by you).